# Extjs filefield button only with an image

Tags: javascript, extjs, filefield

Please help me. can I modify the browse button with an image? So, if user clik on image, browse dialog is shown. Im newbie with Extjs. I try with iconCls, but its not working :/

[please check this image](http://s23.postimg.org/822h6vtuz/Screen_Shot_2013_05_01_at_7_33_56_AM.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Use the [buttonConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-cfg-buttonConfig) configuration option. You can specify `iconCls` there. That's how they do it in [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/form/file-upload.html)

```
{
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'photo',
    fieldLabel: 'Photo',
    labelWidth: 50,
    msgTarget: 'side',
    allowBlank: false,
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonConfig: {
        text: 'Hello',
        iconCls: 'test-class'
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you its working. but, can I change the button with image? so, if user clik the image, it will browse . please check this [link](http://s23.postimg.org/822h6vtuz/Screen_Shot_2013_05_01_at_7_33_56_AM.png)